# Ordinary generating function for Lah's numbers $L(n,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, self-learning

I'm studing signed Lah's numbers $L(n,k) = (-1)^n\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

It's easy to show that exponential generating function for the sequence $\{L(n,k)\}_{n\geq0}$ is equal to
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}L(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)^k.
$$
So what's about ordinary generating function $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}L(n,k)x^n = ?$. I'm trying to apply connection between ordinary generating function $A(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ and exponential generating function $B(t) = \sum a_n \frac{t^n}{n!}$:
$$
A(x) = \int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-t}B(xt)dt,
$$
to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}L(n,k)x^n = x\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x+k}{1-kx}$.

So how to prove it?

Comment: What's the meaning of the infinite product in the right hand side? It doesn't seem well-defined, as the coefficient near $x$ would be a product of all natural numbers... Should the product be up to $n$ instead of $\infty$?

Comment: Also note that $L(n,k)$ has alternating signs, while $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{x+k}{1-kx}$ only has positive coefficients in the expansion.

Comment: And in the LHS, the summation should probably be over $x^n$ rather than $x^k$

Comment: But even then, the expansion of LHS doesn't match that of RHS... So, I fail to understand what exactly we need to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $k$, note that $L(n,1) = (-1)^n n!$, so for $k=1$ the power series would be
$$
\sum\limits_{n} (-1)^n n! x^n.
$$
The problem is, this power series doesn't converge for any real $x \neq 0$, so it can't be expressed as an analytical function. The terms grow even faster for larger $k$, so it's true for them as well.

If you want an OGF with a fixed $n$ rather than fixed $k$, you essentially get [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials), which are also quite far from the form that you want to prove in your question.

As I also mentioned in the comments, the RHS of your expression doesn't meaningfully converge, and if we limit the product up to $k$ rather than up to $\infty$, we get something that seems to have nothing to do with Lahs numbers. So, I don't think this question can be meaningfully answered without further clarification.

Comment: Kulkov, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary generating function is a divergent series for all $k\ge 1$. However, it is a Borel summable one. The Borel sum may be expressed in terms of the Kummer $U$-function:
\begin{align*}
A(x) &= \frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - t} \left( {\frac{{xt}}{{1 + xt}}} \right)^k {\rm d}t}  = \frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - t/x} \left( {\frac{t}{{1 + t}}} \right)^k {\rm d}t} \\ & = ( - 1)^k \frac{1}{x}U(k + 1,2,1/x) = ( - 1)^k U(k,0,1/x)
\end{align*}
(cf. [$(13.4.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4.E4) and [$(13.2.40)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E40)). The formal generating function arises as the asymptotic expansion as $x\to 0^+$ of this function:
$$
( - 1)^k U(k,0,1/x) \sim x^k \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + k} \frac{{(k)_n (k + 1)_n }}{{n!}}x^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = k}^\infty  {L(n,k)x^n } 
$$
(use [Watson's lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.ii) or [$(13.7.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.7.E3)).